# How to update summary when using NeweyWest?

Tags: r, summary, lm

I am using NeweyWest standard errors to correct my `lm() / dynlm()` output. E.g.:

```
fit1<-dynlm(depvar~covariate1+covariate2)
coeftest(fit1,vcov=NeweyWest)
```

Coefficients are displayed the way I´d like to, but unfortunately I loose all the regression output information like R squared, F-Test etc. that is displayed by summary. So I wonder how I can display robust se and all the other stuff in the same summary output.

Is there a way to either get everything in one call or to overwrite the 'old' estimates?
I bet I just missed something badly, but that is really relevant when sweaving the output.

Test example, taken from `?dynlm`.

```
require(dynlm)
require(sandwich)
data("UKDriverDeaths", package = "datasets")
uk <- log10(UKDriverDeaths)
dfm <- dynlm(uk ~ L(uk, 1) + L(uk, 12))

#shows R-squared, etc.
summary(dfm)

#no such information
coeftest(dfm, vcov = NeweyWest)
```

btw.: same applies for `vcovHC`

Comment: So we're clear, is that `dynlm` from the `dynlm` package, `NeweyWest` from the `sandwich` package, and `coeftest` from the `lmtest` package?

Comment: @ran2, can you please add the necessary `library` or `require` statements to your question so that it becomes reproducible?

Comment: sorry guys... thought with the stomach.. lunchtime and I was starving. edited my post. Thank you @Richie Cotton for helping out!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`coefficients` is just a matrix in the `lm` (or `dynlm`) summary object, so all you need to do is `unclass` the `coeftest()` output.

```
library(dynlm)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
temp.lm <- dynlm(runif(100) ~ rnorm(100))
temp.summ <- summary(temp.lm)
temp.summ$coefficients <- unclass(coeftest(temp.lm, vcov. = NeweyWest))
```

Comment: thx so much, unclass was exactly the piece I was missing. sry for the delayed accept though.

Comment: Does Newey West change the estimator though? All I see is that it changes the covariance of the estimator, which in turn changes hypothesis testing...

Comment: @YeTian No it doesn't change the estimators as far as I know. It only changes the hypothesis testing and confidence intervals.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the covariance matrix, the F-statistics change and you need to compute it again using `waldtest()` right?  Because

```
temp.summ$coefficients <- unclass(coeftest(temp.lm, vcov. = NeweyWest))
```

only overwrites the coefficients.
F-statistics change but R^2 remains the same .